# How to set @Html.Checkbox() is checked when clicking the text beside?

Tags: html, css, razor, checkbox

I have a line which contains a checkbox and a text. Like this: `@Html.Checkbox("cb1") @: My checkbox`, and the requirement is: When I hover `"My checkbox"`, the checkbox `cb1` is hovered. When I click `"My checkbox"`, `cb1` is clicked.

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<tr>
     <td>@Html.Checkbox("cb1")</td>
     <td><label id="text">My checkbox</label></td>
</tr>
```

with CSS:

```
#text:hover #cb1:hover
{
/* I mean: if #text is hovered, then #cb1 is hovered too. But it doesn't work */
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any CSS.
Just set the `for` attribute in the `<label>` to the ID of the control it identifies.